# How to implement a hybrid Transport Layer Protocol?

Tags: linux, dynamic, tcp, header, udp

I'm hoping to create a hybrid like transport layer protocol which can adapt itself according to the data sent from the application layer. This new protocol should be able to identify and transmit urgent data very quickly by lowering the header size (by utilizing a UDP like header) and when it's not urgent it should switch back to a TCP like header.

So now my questions are:

- will I be able to implement this dynamic header by modifying eg: tcp.c/udp.c files (found in directory Linux/net/ipv4/) in the Linux kernel?
- And also is there a way to simulate the execution of the tcp.c code to get an idea?

NOTE: I don't want to switch between TCP and UDP protocols. I want to have a separate protocol which uses a dynamic header according to the data it receives.

Comment: I recommend that you explain in detail why existing technologies are not suitable for your problem and you need to invent your own. Maybe even describe the underlying problem you are trying to solve with this kind of new protocol.

Comment: You mention switching based on urgency, later on also mention you don't prefer urgency? The application needs to bind to a port isn't? It should know what is the protocol below. How will the peer know about the change you make on one side? What happens for TCP connection when you switch to UDP? Isn't that overhead? You can invent new protocol rather than combining the two. But as @SteffenUllrich said whats the current limitations of TCP/UDP for your needs?

Comment: The issues of protocol are many and varied.  You're unlikely to accomplish anything on your own that would better that simply keeping both a TCP and UDP socket open and connected (yes, UDP can be "connected" even though it's connectionless) and sending data as appropriate.  (Or at least state _why_ that is undesireable.)  Or you could try using "TCP Urgent" but it's not a very well document (indeed, it's often not even implemented correctly): http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPPriorityDataTransferUrgentFunction-2.htm